# Deleting characters lines from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, line

I have some XML files which contains lines with string characters (garbage) that I want to remove from the file.
I'm searching a code which can do that, can someone help me with that?

```
<value key="EE_BELL_TIME">
  <val name="Siren Time" show="1" type="BYTE" size="8" poff="260" psize="8" pbitoff="0" />
  <posvalues>
    <pval name="1 minute" num="1" />
    zeqmmzv
    <pval name="3 minutes" num="3" />
    <pval name="4 minutes" num="4" />
    <pval name="8 minutes" num="8" />
    fmengu
    <pval name="10 minutes" num="10" />
    <pval name="15 minutes" num="15" />
    p
    <pval name="20 minutes" num="20" />
  </posvalues>
</value>
```

Comment: dunno if its a fast solution, but maybe do a regex that defines the markup and what the markup contains, like attributes and stuff, then get the match collection and write it all to a new file, i would think that would be the easiest way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a very simple way:

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(xmlPath);
 File.WriteAllLines(xmlPath, lines.Where(l => l.StartsWith("<") && l.EndsWith(">")));
```

This is just a very simple solution, but it should work for your xml-file

Update-Code

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(xmlFile, encoding);
        List<string> result = lines.Select(line => line.TrimStart().TrimEnd()).Where(trim => trim.StartsWith("<") && trim.EndsWith(">")).ToList();
        File.WriteAllLines("XmlFile2.xml", result, encoding);
```

Update to not trim the lines:

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(xmlFile, encoding);
        List<string> result = (from line in lines let trim = line.TrimStart().TrimEnd() where trim.StartsWith("<") && trim.EndsWith(">") select line).ToList();
        File.WriteAllLines("XmlFile2.xml", result, encoding);
```

Comment: What if the XML has no line breaks?

Comment: Then the code-snipped fails. as i said: it's a very simple solution, but it should work for the xml provided. probably there's a better way.

Comment: When I'm running this code (Tomtom user) and saving the content to a new XML file, it saved it to an empty XML file, why?
There is something wrong that I forgot to do before or after it?

Comment: I updated my code. I tried it with this code with your xml and it works fine

Comment: @Tomtom OK, now its works better, but it does not reserve the spaces and tabs that every line starts with, in the result file all the tags (fathers and child's) starting in the same position (position 0 in every line).

Comment: I made another update of the code

Answer (score 1):

In `C#`, you can use a regular expression as a solution to find the XML tags, like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Open and read into a string the file containing the XML
        string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("file.xml");

        // You have too match (?>\<).*(?>\>), which also removes the line feeds
        var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?>\<).*(?>\>)");

        // Use a StringBuilder to append the matches
        var sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop through the matches
        foreach (Match item in matches)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(item.Value);
        }

        // Show the result
        Console.WriteLine(sBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the XML has nested elements?

Comment: Will that regex work in that case?

Comment: For that matter, will it work on `<pval name="1 minute" num="1" ></pval>`?

Comment: The proposed answer works for the given example, which contains nested elements.

Comment: I just checked it, and yes, it works.